# mysql background increase of a value of column at regular intervals

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans

I have a database in mysql. I want to increase the value of a particular column by a specific amount. I have interfaced this database with a java application(via netbeans). I believe this can happen only at the database level through a stored procedure or a function.
The column say 'x' needs to be increased by 1000 if the difference between sysdate and date(another column) is greater than 15 days.

I cannot do this through a trigger on the application side, because that will require logging into the application and if the trigger isnt triggered, the schduled increase wouldn't happen.

Help me out!

Comment: Sunny, there is a way to do this from both Java and the database level. Can you please explain more about your situation: Are you looking for one-time a script that will update already existing values in a table to which you recently added the ‘X’ column? Or you want to regularly populate ‘X’ while inserting new records from Java side?

Comment: I want to update that column regularly. I dont want a script to run daily. I want it to be taken care of automatically. Thats why I prefer from database side

Comment: Well in that case I suggest you to do it from Java side. 

Main reasons: 
• Java vs DB: databases are a lot faster, but this wouldn't matter much unless you are going to update very large amount of rows. 
• Since you probably already have a Java method that persists this object, it will be easy to integrate an “if” statement in it and just increase field ‘X’ with 1000 or when that “if” statement passes or not.

If you share a portion of your code that is populating and persisting the object I can prepare changes for it.

Comment: Thanks Georgi. I was able to do it from DB side as well as Java side.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create trigger for insert statement. For example;

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_check BEFORE INSERT ON yourTable
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.amount < 0 THEN
            SET NEW.amount = 0;
        ELSEIF NEW.amount > 100 THEN
            SET NEW.amount = 100;
        END IF;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an EVENT in MYSQL. E.g.

```
CREATE EVENT event_update_something
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 10 SECOND
    DO
      ALL YOUR LOGIC HERE
```

See more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html)

OR you can define Sheduler on java side e.g. Quartz job. If you use spring. See an example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/)

Anyway you should define an action which is invoked periodically (e.g. 10 seconds interval). The action checks some state and update necessary data.